# readonly changing the behavior of a struct

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly

I'm trying to understand some basic concepts:

```
class Program
{
   private static readonly MyStruct m = new MyStruct();
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //new MutableSample().RunSample();

       Console.WriteLine(m.ChangeInternal());
       Console.WriteLine(m.ChangeInternal());
       Console.WriteLine(m.ChangeInternal());
       Console.Read();
    }
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    private int x;
    public int ChangeInternal()
    {
        this.x = this.x + 1;
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

When I run this code it gives me 1, 1, 1, but when I remove the "readonly" it says 1, 2, 3.

Can someone explain to me this?

Answer (score 5):

Section 7.5.4 of the C# specs states:

> [...] if the field is readonly and the reference occurs outside an instance constructor of the class in which the field is declared, then the result is a value, namely the value of the field I in the object referenced by E

So when the field is `readonly` you're mutating a copy (since it's impossible to mutate a value, only a variable).  When it isn't you're mutating the field itself.

This is described in more detail in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx) by Eric Lippert.  To quote its ending:

> This is yet another reason why mutable value types are evil. Try to always make value types immutable.

Comment: Is it just me, or the example given by Eric Lippert is exactly like the OPs?

Comment: @Mihai It's *really* close.  There are a few differences that aren't germane to the problem at hand.